# Drag n drop file download in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-download

I am looking for a specific file download functionality.  Hopefully I can explain it correctly.

Drag file download link to the open windows explorer folder.  (Doing this currently only downloads the html file to the download link.  It would be awesome if it would actually download the file)

--This one is a a feature of HTML5, but I am sure there has to be a program that does it for you regardless of html version, but I just have not found it.

OR.....

1. Firstly, you have windows explorer open to a specific folder
   location.
2. In a web browser, you click a download link to download a file. The Save As dialog pops up to ask you where to save.
3. You then click your open windows explorer window to make it active.
   (the window in #1).  This then tells the program to download the
   file to that location.

Anything like this out there?  I often save multiple file types throughout the day, and not all the same file types are saved to the same directory.  And I always have QT tabbed windows explorer open, so it would be fast to just quickly select the open folder to save, instead of browsing to the folder in the Save As Dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the page/webserver in question, most of the links clicked go to a HTML download page which then redirects to one of a number of different download servers based on their traffic/availability and the user's location. Seamless for the user, but stops 'leeching' programs and any server outages, manages load, etc.

I've previously used a download manager 'FlashGet' which had similar features you are asking for, it would monitor the clipboard so I could literally 'copy' any location and then if it redirected to a one of the filetypes (you could specify) it would pop up a download 'box'. It would also monitor clicks within browsers for files not opened by them (and downloadable). Think there was even a 'Drop box' you could drag links onto, to download (but I never used it).

**Note: This was pre-Windows 7**

Comment: You can drag and drop into download managers, but the files are still download to predefined folders.  I basically need on the fly selection of the folder.  Just drag into the folder and the file is now downloaded to that folder.  Say for instance I am downloading a a tar.gz file.  The link to the tar.gz file is on the page, and I drag that link into an explorer folder, and that file is downloaded to that folder.  Download managers don't have that functionality.  They just aid in the downloading; so you can resume downloads, downloads don't get corrupt, and faster downloads.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible without changing the way you browse and/or use Windows... There may be 3rd party shell programs with this feature.